# SQL code for anagram

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, boolean-logic, anagram

I have  a SQL code for finding whether two words are anagram or not.

```
DECLARE @str1 VARCHAR(100), @str2 VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @str1 = 'mmaa', @str2 = 'mama'

IF LEN(@str1) <> LEN(@str2)
  BEGIN
    SELECT 'NOT EQUAL'
  END 

ELSE
  BEGIN

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM

    (

    select  substring(@str1, number, 1) as data
        from    master..spt_values as m 
        where   m.type='p' and number <= len(@str1) AND number > 0

    UNION 

    select  substring(@str2, number, 1) as data
        from    master..spt_values as m 
        where   m.type='p' and number <= len(@str2) AND number > 0
        )
t)

= LEN(@str1)


    SELECT '1 anagram'
ELSE

SELECT '0 not anagram'
END
```

But for words like mmaa and mama this program returns not anagram.  But they are anagrams.  How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps use a language better suited for this?  If you insist on using SQL, you'll need to use library functions that work better with the individual characters than just ANSI SQL.  Do you have a specific DBMS you will be using?

Comment: i have to use sql.i'm using mssql management studio 2008R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rather crude, but how about:

```
Declare @S1 varChar(100) = 'mmaa'
Declare @S2 varChar(100) = 'mama'

Declare @c char(1)
Declare @i tinyint
Declare @o1 varChar(100) = ''
Declare @o2 varChar(100) = ''
While DataLength(@s1) > 0 Begin
   Set @c = Left(@s1, 1)
   Set @s1 = Substring(@s1, 2, len(@s1))
   Set @i = 1

   While @i <= Len(@o1) And @c > substring(@o1, @i, 1) Set @i += 1
   Set @o1 = left(@o1, @i-1) + @c + substring(@o1, @i, len(@o1))
End
While DataLength(@s2) > 0 Begin
   Set @c = Left(@s2, 1)
   Set @s2 = Substring(@s2, 2, len(@s2))
   Set @i = 1

   While @i <= Len(@o2) And @c > substring(@o2, @i, 1) Set @i += 1
   Set @o2 = left(@o2, @i-1) + @c + substring(@o2, @i, len(@o2))
End
Select case When @o1 = @o2 Then 'Anagram' Else 'Not Anagram' End
```

or to encapsulate the sort into a function,

```
    Create FUNCTION [dbo].[SortString](@s varChar(8000))
    RETURNS varChar(8000)
    As
    Begin
        Declare @c char(1)
        Declare @i int
        Declare @out varChar(8000) = left(@s, 1)
        While DataLength(@s) > 0 Begin
            Set @s = Substring(@s, 2, len(@s)-1)
            Set @c = Left(@s, 1)
            Set @i = 0
            While @i < Len(@out) And @c > substring(@out, @i+1, 1) Set @i += 1
            Set @out = case when @i < Len(@out) 
        then stuff(@out, @i+1, 0, @c)
        else  @out + @c end  
        End
        return  @out
    End
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `CHECKSUM_AGG`

```
DECLARE @str1 VARCHAR(100), @str2 VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @str1 = 'mmaa', @str2 = 'mama'

IF LEN(@str1) <> LEN(@str2)
  BEGIN
    SELECT 'NOT EQUAL'
  END 
ELSE
  BEGIN
    IF(SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*))
        FROM   (select  substring(@str1, number, 1) as data
            from    master..spt_values as m 
            where   m.type='p' and number <= len(@str1) AND number > 0)T1)=
    (SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*))
        FROM   (select  substring(@str2, number, 1) as data
            from    master..spt_values as m 
            where   m.type='p' and number <= len(@str2) AND number > 0)T2)
        SELECT '1 anagram'
    ELSE
        SELECT '0 not anagram'
END
```